# How should I flush my refrigerators drinking water system after storage?

Tags: refrigerator, mold

Have a refrigerator that has been turned off and left closed!  It has a ice maker and water line.  How do I go about making sure that it is safe to use the ice and water?

Comment: I would flush the system with fresh water and throw away the first couple of batches of ice. If it has a filter that should be changed also. If on city water the small amount of chlorine will help clean it if on a well you might want to add a couple of drops of bleach in the supply line prior to flushing and flush at least a gallon of water or until the smell is gone.

Comment: Follow instructions from @Ed Beal, but you should bypass the filter when you flush the system, this will give a much higher flow rate through the system and hopefully blow out any crap.

Answer (score 1):

When using a home that has been left unused for quite some time, typically all you need to do is flush the lines before using.  I suspect a refrigerator would be the same.

1. Clean out ice maker
2. Flush water lines by running 1 - 2 gallons though it
3. Turn on ICE maker and dispose of first 2 full loads of ice

Comment: I'm inclined to upvote, but I wonder if you have any references that would convince me that dangerous bacteria (think Legionnaires') or your standard icky stuff (mildew) will be adequately removed this way?